# Phonegap functions not defined in Phonegap build apps - also pushNotifications don't work

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am having trouble to get phonegap working properly. The phonegap function/objects don't seem to be working. Also push notifications don't work too even though I have included the plugin using the proper CLI command and have made sure that all the files are in the correct places according to the documentation. I have use javascript code from the PushNotifications plugin documentation so I assume it is correct also.

I have installed PhoneGap on Mac OS X 10.8.4 and created a new PhoneGap project using the CLI interface.

Then I wrote the HTML/CSS/JavaScript files for the app and placed them in the www directory.
I used the following command to build and run the application on my android device:

```
phonegap local run android
```

It worked fine and the application launched on my device. Everything worked fine.
Then I added some code that uses phonegap's functions/objects and tried to run it on android again. 
The app ran fine again, but this time the following code did not execute:

```
alert(device.platform);
```

Also the PushNotifications code did not execute too due to an error (device is not defined)
I have tried to include cordova.js, phonegap.js, both of them at the same time or even none of them, but the result is still same.

I checked to see if the platforms/android/assets/www folder in the project directory contained the correct files, and it did. Both cordova.js and phonegap.js files were automatically added (phonegap build command adds both files for backward compatibility reasons, at least thats how I understood it).

So I am trying to figure out why device object is undefined even when phonegap.js file exists in the www folder and is included in the html file. I think if I can get the "alert(device.platform);" code working then the push notification code would work too, as it fails at the if statement that has to evaluate device.platform.

Here is the code for the index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My App</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/functions.js"></script>
        <script src="js/fastclick.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="PushNotification.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://debug.build.phonegap.com/target/target-script-min.js#f997ffa0-5ed6-11e2-84ec-12313d1744da"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        //*********************************************************
        // Wait for Cordova to Load
        //*********************************************************

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
        //THE FOLLOWING CODE IS RESPONSIBLE FOR PUSH NOTIFICATIONS
        var pushNotification;

            alert(device.platform);

            try { 
                pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
                if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering android</li>');
                    pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"hidden-by-me","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"});     // required!
                } else {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering iOS</li>');
                    pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});    // required!
                }
            }
            catch(err) { 
                txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n"; 
                txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n"; 
                alert(txt); 
            } 

            //Rest of the code

            updateData();
            if (window.localStorage.getItem("default-school") == "infant") {
                window.location.replace("infant.html");
            } else 
            if (window.localStorage.getItem("default-school") == "junior") {
                window.location.replace("junior.html");
            };
        }

    // iOS
    function onNotificationAPN(event) {
        if (event.alert) {
            navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);
        }

        if (event.sound) {
            var snd = new Media(event.sound);
            snd.play();
        }

        if (event.badge) {
            pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, errorHandler, event.badge);
        }
    }

    // Android
    function onNotificationGCM(e) {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

        switch( e.event ) {
            case 'registered':
                if ( e.regid.length > 0 ) {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
                    // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                    // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                    console.log("regID = " + e.regID);
                }
                break;

            case 'message':
                // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
                // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
                if (e.foreground) {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');

                    // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
                    var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+e.soundname);
                    my_media.play();
                }
                else {
                    // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
                    if (e.coldstart) $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                    else $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                }

                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
                break;

            case 'error':
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
                break;

            default:
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
                break;
        }
    }

    function tokenHandler (result) {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>token: '+ result +'</li>');
        // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
        // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
    }

    function successHandler (result) {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:'+ result +'</li>');
    }

    function errorHandler (error) {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:'+ error +'</li>');
    }
</script>
    </head>
<body onload="initFastButtons();init();">
    <span id="fastclick">

        <div id="main">
            <ul id="app-status-ul">
                <li>Push Plugin test</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

It would be really great if anyone could help me out on this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Which version of phonegap are you using?

If v3 then did you install the 'device' plugin?

```
$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
```

Comment: I actually am using version 3. It worked! All I had to do is add the device plugin. Its very strange that I don't recall seeing any mention of 'device' plugin in the push notifications plugin. Anyway, thanks a lot mate. I have been stuck on this for ages :)

Comment: I got caught out by the same issue mate! Glad that fixed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to get this working in Phonegap Build for a long time and finally figured it out:

config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" /> <!-- Needed to use device.model (Not available until document deviceready event-->
```

javascript:

```js
function deviceReady() {
  
  alert(device.model);
  
  }

document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceReady, false);
```

However, I found out this object is not needed for the information i was looking for (device.model and device.version) because it was available in **navigator.userAgent**.
The version is the Android version number in the useragent string and the device model is right after "Android" in the useragent string.